# setup ichat message app with localhost ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I have setup one ejabberd server on mac and create two user using admin panel. I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958) for testing of xmpp server. I successfully setup user in Adium. Now I want to setup user in mac ichat app using localhost but It is not connecting to my localhost server.

Comment: Did you enter the correct port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve issue by setting server name and port

Server name : localhost

Port : 5222